# Confusion regarding boxing of value types

Tags: c#

In the following code...

```
 int i=5;  
 object o = 5;
 Console.WriteLine(o); //prints 5
```

**I have three questions:**

**1)** What additional/useful  functionality  is acquired by the `5`  residing in the variable `o`   that the `5` represented by the variable `i` does not have ?

**2)** If some code is expecting a value type then  we can just pass it the int `i` , but if its expecting a reference type , its probably not interested in the 5 boxed in `o` anyway . So when are boxing conversions explicitly used in code  ?

**3)** How come the `Console.WriteLine(o)` print out a 5 instead of System.Object ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What additional/useful functionality is acquired by the 5 residing in the variable o that the 5 represented by the variable i does not have ?

It's rare that you *want* to box something, but occasionally it is *necessary* to do so. In older versions of .NET boxing was often necessary because some methods only worked with `object` (e.g. ArrayList's methods). This is much less of a problem now that there is generics, so boxing occurs less frequently in newer code.

> If some code is expecting a value type then we can just pass it the int i, but if its expecting a reference type, its probably not interested in the 5 boxed in o anyway . So when are boxing conversions explicitly used in code ?

In practice boxing usually happens automatically for you. You could explicitly box a variable if you want to make it more clear to the reader of your code that boxing is happening. This might be relevant if performance could be an issue.

> How come the Console.WriteLine(o) print out a 5 instead of System.Object ??

Because `ToString` is a virtual method on `object` which means that the implementation that is called depends on the runtime type, not the static type. Since `int` overrides `ToString` with its own implementation, it is `int.ToString` that is called, not the default implementation provided by `object`.

```
object o = 5;
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());  // outputs System.Int32, not System.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

> What additional/useful functionality is acquired by the 5 residing in the variable o that the 5 represented by the variable i does not have ?

There is no additional functionality acquired by a boxed value type, apart from the fact that it can be passed by referenced to code that requires that.

> So when are boxing conversions explicitly used in code ?

I can't spontaneously think of a scenario when you would need to explicitly box an `int` to an `object`, since there is always an implicit conversion in that direction (although I would not be surprised if there are cases when an explicit conversion is required).

> How come the Console.WriteLine(o) print out a 5 instead of System.Object ??

It calls `ToString` on the object passed. In fact, it starts by trying to convert the object to an [`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx) and, if successful (which it will be in the case of an `int`) then calls the [`ToString` overload that is defined in that interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring.aspx). This will return "5".

Answer (score 0):

1) On its own, there is not much point. But imagine you wish to store something in a generic way, and you don't know whether that thing is a value or an object. With boxing, you can convert the value into an object, and then treat everything as an object. Wihtout it, you would need a special case to be able to hold a value *or* an object. (THis is most useful in containers such as lists, allowing you to mix values like 5 with references to objects like a FileStream).

2) Boxing conversions usually only happen implicitly, except in example code illustrating boxing.

3) The WriteLine code probably calls the virtual Object.ToString() method. If the class of the Object it calls this on does not override ToString, then it will call the base class (object) implementation, but most types (including System.Int  although int is a value type, it is still derived from System.Object) override this to provide a more useful context-specific result.

Answer (score 0):

Additional functionality: The object is a full-fledged object. You can call methods on it and use it as you would any other object:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("type: {0}", o.GetType());
System.Console.WriteLine("hash code: {0}", o.GetHashCode());
```

The int variable is a value type, not an object.

**XXX:** This is incorrect; see comments. I would venture instead that the one difference in how you might use the two is that `object o = 5` is nullable (you can set `o = null`), while the value type is not - if `int i = 5`, then `i` is always an int.

Explicit boxing: As you said, the boxed version is used by coding manipulating objects as objects rather than integers in particular. This is what enables non-type-safe generic data structures. Now that type-safe generic data structures are available, you are unlikely to be doing much casting and boxing/unboxing.

Why "5": Because the object knows how to print itself using `ToString()`.

Comment: This is a little misleading. You can call GetType() and GetHasCode() etc on a variable of type Int32. That has nothing to do with the value type being boxed or not.

Comment: @KeithMahoney You are right: I was wrong. I pulled out the C# 3.0 language spec, and the type system is nicely unified. The central difference - value versus reference type - concerns how an object is related to its data.